# Numerically calculate the boundary of a basin of attraction for a high dimensional dynamical system

Tags: numerical-methods, dynamical-systems

I am looking for an efficient, non-exponential time algorithm to calculate the boundary of a basin of attraction for a stable fixed point in a high dimensional nonlinear dynamical system. The naive method (simulating the system, finding points "close" to other points in a different basin) appears to require an exponentially increasing number of points to maintain a similar density of points (since the basin boundary is expected to be an $N-1$ dimensional manifold), and is thus not really feasible.

Alternatively, if anyone knows of something saying this isn't possible, that would be useful too.

Thanks!

Comment: As you say, the boundary should be $N-1$ dimensional.  But it may be fractal, highly non-smooth and maybe not even  a manifold.
What form of output would you be looking for?

Comment: I recommend you look into GAIO. http://www2.math.uni-paderborn.de/ags/ag-dellnitz/software.html . It is defintiely better than the naive method, since it is based on adaptive subdivision.

Comment: That GAIO link is no longer working, see https://github.com/gaioguy/GAIO